# How to convert a list class object to float numpy array iteratively

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

```
l_array = np.array([[0.0,0.0]])

quotes = [758529,3930881]


   for i in quotes:

       try:
           v = [item["last_price"] for item in ticks if item['instrument_token'] == i]
           a = v[0]

       except:
           continue
       i_array = np.array[[instrument_token,a]]
l_array = np.append(i_array)
print(l_array)
[[0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00]
 [7.58529e+06 11.487000e+01]
 [3.930881e+06 9.985000e+01]]
```

> Here ticks is a list class object(API Callback function output) that
>   has to be converted to a numpy array(array within an array) to be
>   saved as a .npy file, I can't seem to do this as the output i.e.
>   l_array gives me a numpy array of complex numbers. The output must be
>   a float numpy array.

Comment: Why do you think that complex numbers are involved?

Comment: The output seems as though the type is complex however the type is float I can't seem to figure out what is happening when the i_array is declared, all the issues seem to start there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `l_array.astype(float)`

Comment: can you try to convert each i_array before append

Comment: I think you can use vstack or hstack instead of append

Comment: The append method performs correctly, problem occurs when the i_array is declared.

Comment: [SOLVED] I used >> i_array = np.array([[instrument_token,a]], dtype = object)